# Can you list Mail attachments separately rather than as icons in the text?

Tags: mail.app

In Mail, is it possible to show attachments in a separate list (like in Entourage) rather than as icons buried within the text?

Answer (score 4):

The following command can be entered into terminal to disable the inline display of Mail's Attachments:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

to restore the original functionality, use this:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool no
```

Comment: On my computer the attachments are still embedded in the text, but with an icon rather than a preview. If I start writing an email and add an attachment, the attachment is placed right where the text cursor is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Entourage shows attachments.  However, in 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and earlier, you can view all of the attachments in one place by clicking the triangle disclosure arrow next to the paper clip icon below the headers in the message view.  They will still show as icons, but this shows all of the attachments in one place.  The attachment icons will also continue to be shown inline in the text.

In 10.7 (Lion), this button stays below the headers, but moves to the right side of the screen.  Click and hold and it will list all the attachments in a pull-down menu.  Again, the icons will continue to be shown inline in the text.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same "problem" and I have found two possible solutions for this. One, you can use the terminal command that, however, would only sort out the outgoing e-mails (for some it would not be a problem, but I have had PDFs coming in that would slow down my mail.app'. Two, there is an app called "Attachment tamer" where you can pretty much adjust any aspect in relation to e-mail attachments. Nevertheless, it costs 15 $. So, after a couple of hours I have found out a solution that works for both, outgoing and incoming mails, and does not cost anything. The "magic" app is called "TinkerTool" and it only does take two clicks and two reboots to have all the attachments displayed as symbols only. Download the App - install it - run it - tab: applications - check the 6th box from the top. And it is for free. Additionally, it has many other features which you can use. Enjoy ;-)

Marek

Comment: Tinkertool is the best answer on this thread. It's excellent, and it's free. One weirdly necessary trick from the Tinkertool docs: you need to close the application you're changing preferences for (Mail, in this case) before you change the pref in Tinkertool. Then wait ten seconds, doing nothing at the keyboard, for the setting to "stick" (!). Then open the application and test that it's working. (This is a Mac OS defect, not a tinkertool defect.)

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the attachment and choose View As Icon. If you want View as Icon as the default check out Attachment Tamer

http://lokiware.info/Attachment-Tamer